# How is a member function found based on this pointer of the derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, this, static-typing

Consider the following example:

```
struct B1 {
    void f() {
        this->g();
        std::cout << this << std::endl;
    }
    void g() {
        std::cout << "B1::g" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B2 {
    void f() {
        this->g();
        std::cout << this << std::endl;
    }
    void g() {
        std::cout << "B2::g" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct C: B1, B2 {
    void f() {
        B1::f();
        B2::f();
        std::cout << this << std::endl;
    }
    void g() {
        std::cout << "C::g" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.f();
    return 0;
}
```

For me, the output is:

```
B1::g
0x7fffa11436b7
B2::g
0x7fffa11436b7
0x7fffa11436b7
```

Let us focus on `B2::f`. As seen from the output, inside `B2::f`, `this` points to the beginning of the object of type `C`. So, how is `this->g()` resolved correctly to `B2::g()`?

Comment: What else would it resolve to? What would you expect it to be *other* than `B2::g()`? Though the mechanism of the actual call isn't defined by the language standard, the resolution certainly is. Regardless, compiling this to asm you'll probably discover `this->g()` is little more than a simple push of `this` (with register optimization obviously potential) and straight-up-invoke of `B::g()`. After all, `g()` isn't virtual.

Comment: The pointer values are misleading you. Add a data member to each of the three structs and try again.

Answer (score 0):

No functions are virtual here. So you you call `g` member function from `B1::f` you call *by definition* `B1::g`. Things would indeed go differently if `g` was virtual, because then all `f` functions would call `C::g` (just try to replace `void g()` with `virtual void g()` in all 3 structs)